# mic input working in simulator, not on phone xcode

Tags: xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I am trying to program an app that uses average power to the mic to trigger a game response. I am using the following code in `-init`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],   AVNumberOfChannelsKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,il];

NSError *error;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(myMethod:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

in my method
float soundLevel=[recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];

The triggering is working fine in the simulator but not working when i put it on my phone to test. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This solution helped me get the microphone to work.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350420/how-to-detect-a-blow-in-the-microphone-with-unity-and-ios

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `@"/dev/null"` is a valid path on the device. Your app can't read or write outside its sandbox, so setting up an instance of AVAudioRecorder to record to /dev/null  probably isn't going to work.

Try giving it a path to a file in your app's Documents folder instead.